# writing a class decorator

Tags: numpy, python-decorators

i have a class that has a method called my_func(x,s,n).   I need to vectorize this function.  That is to say, i want to be able to pass x = [3,4,5,6,7] or any range of values and it gives me a result.  I am using numpy and looking through here, i managed to find a solution that works.  However, I want to make it object oriented.  I tried this:

```
class Vectorize:
    """vectorization wrapper that works with instance methods"""
    def __init__(self, otypes=None, signature=None):
        self.otypes = otypes
        self.sig = signature

    # Decorator as an instance method
    def decorator(self, fn):
        vectorized = np.vectorize(fn, otypes=self.otypes, signature=self.sig)

        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return vectorized(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

and then i tried this:

```
@Vectorize(signature=("(),(),(),()->()"))
def my_func(self, k: int, s: float, n: int):
```

I keep getting an error, Vectorize object is not callable.  Is there any other way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Before you invest too much time in this project, pay attention to the performance disclaimer.  The use of `signature` further degrades performance.

Comment: `np.vectorize` can be used as a decorator directly, though I don't how to provide the `otypes` or `sig` values.   `partial` might help, but I haven't worked with decorators much.  It's python code (or at least was in the past), but I don't where it is in the `github` repository.  But I suspect this is purely a decorator code issue, not `numpy` specific.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue.  But, now that you have said signature degrades performance, I'm considering alternate solution.  For those who are curious:

```
class Vectorize:
"""vectorization decorator that works with instance methods"""
def vectorize(self, otypes=None, signature=None):
    # Decorator as an instance method
    def decorator(fn):
        vectorized = np.vectorize(fn, otypes=otypes, signature=signature)

        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return vectorized(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class CustomClass:
    v = Vectorize()
    
   @v.vectorize(signature=("(),(),(),()->()"))
   def my_func(self, k: int, s: float, n: int):
```